# Converting array ["null", "0", "1", "2", "2", "1", "0"] to ["1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 'b', '1.1.2', '1.2']

Tags: java, serialization, groovy, nested-lists

I have already spent all attempts to resolve this. :) and i ask for help.

---

for understanding:

"null" - paragraph ( -> 1, 2, 3, etc)

"number" - parent's position. first subparagraph (-> 1.1, 2.4, etc) if parent is "null", else if parent is "number" second subparagraph (-> 1.1.1, 2.4.2, etc) and else if parent is "number" and has a parent "number" too, then this is third subparagraph (a, b, c instead of 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, etc).

so..

["null", "0", "1", "2", "2", "1", "0"] to ["1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 'b', '1.1.2', '1.2']

- "null": first element "null" -> 1
- "0": second element has parent in position 0. (parent with value "null" in old array or "1" in new array) -> first subparagraph -> 1.1
- "1": third element has parent in position 1. (parent with value "0" in old array or "1.1" in new array) -> second subparagraph -> 1.1.1
- "2": fourth element has parent in position 2. (parent with value "1" in old array or "1.1.1" in new array) -> third subparagraph -> a instead of 1.1.1.1
- "2": fifth element has parent in position 2. (parent with value "1" in old array or "1.1.1" in new array) -> third subparagraph -> a was already -> b
- "1": sixth element has parent in position 1. (parent with value "0" in old array or "1.1" in new array) -> second subparagraph -> 1.1.1 was already -> 1.1.2
- "0": seventh element has parent in position 0. (parent with value "null" in old array or "1" in new array) -> first subparagraph -> 1.1 was already -> 1.2

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear (at least for me). Based on what logic [“null”, “0”, “1”, “2”, “2”, “1”, “0”] should be converted to ["1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 'b', '1.1.2', '1.2']? How `a` and `b` appeared there?

Comment: a = 1.1.1.1, b = 1.1.1.2
this is third subparagraph.

Comment: This looks like important info which should be part of question. Please use [edit] option to provide all necessary info required to understand the problem.

Comment: I added a detailed description. I hope it is more clear..

Comment: If you have solved your problem, the best thing to do is to ADD your own answer. Do not edit adding the solution inside the question itself. This is a Q/A site after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### !UPDATE!

I can not believe it, but I did it!
Here is my new code, if it helps someone.

```
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "0"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.2']
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "1", "2", "null", "4", "5", "6", "null", "8", "9"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 2, '2.1', '2.1.1', 'a', 3, '3.1', '3.1.1']
assert testFunction(["null", "null", "null"]) == [1, 2, 3]
assert testFunction(["null", "null", "1"]) == [1, 2, '2.1']
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "1"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.1.1']
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "null"]) == [1, '1.1', 2]
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "0", "2", "2", "null"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.2.2', 2]
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "1", "2", "2", "1", "0"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 'b', '1.1.2', '1.2']
assert testFunction(["null", "0", "1", "2", "null", "4", "5", "6", "null", "8", "9"]) == [1, '1.1', '1.1.1', 'a', 2, '2.1', '2.1.1', 'a', 3, '3.1', '3.1.1']

def testFunction(array) {
    def count = 1
    def subcount = 1
    char subcountA = 'a'
    def newArray = []
    def value = []

    array.each {
        if (it.isInteger()) {
            value += it as Integer
        }
    }

    def max = value.max()
    if(!max) max = 0

    for(def j = 0 ; j <= max ; j++ ) {
        count = 1
        subcount = 1
        subcountA = 'a'

        for (def i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            def curr_value = array[i]

            if (curr_value == "null") {
                newArray[i] = count
                count++
            }

            if(curr_value == j.toString()) {
                newArray[i] = newArray[j] + "." + subcount
                subcount++

                if(newArray[i].length() > 5) {
                    newArray[i] = subcountA
                    subcountA++
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print(array)
    print(" - ")
    println(newArray)
    return newArray
}
```